# Numerical Integration with Variable Parameters

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

So I want to numerically compute the integral of a long complicated expression over a specified domain (in this case an ellipse). I know how to use a Boole function to sample within the ellipse, but I want to pass a list of points within this ellipse into the function and have the integral be evaluated at each of these specific points. An example would be:

$\frac{1}{(x \cos(\theta)+y \sin(\theta))^\frac{5}{2}} $

So I want to integrate over θ from 0 to 2 π and I want to use different points (x, y) within the specified domain when integrating. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Humm... This integral is zero. So the answer to your question is zero for any x, y

$$\frac{1}{(x \cos(\theta)+y \sin(\theta))^\frac{5}{2}}$$

```
Clear[theta, x, y];
f = 1/(x Cos[theta] + y Sin[theta])^(5/2);
int = Integrate[f, theta];

int /. theta -> 2 Pi
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
int /. theta -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(int /. theta -> 2 Pi) - (int /. theta -> 0) 
(* 0  *)
```

**Update**

From comment below that the function used was just an example, here is one way to make a function to use `NIntegrate` for different `x,y` values. Changed the original function a little bit

```
ClearAll[theta, x, y, f];
f[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}, theta_?NumericQ]:= 1/(x Cos[theta]^2+y Sin[theta])^(5/2);

pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 2}];(*10 points*)

int = NIntegrate[Evaluate@f[#, theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ pts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a made up function just for illustration. Replace your `actual` function by `f` above. If this still not what is being asked, please feel free to follow up.

Comment: Or divergent...

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but that isn't the actual function. The actual function is honestly too long to type, how did you get mathematica output directly into your post? Once I know that I can just post the result directly

Comment: @Nasser Cool, that is helpful. Thank you. So does random real just choose a random set of ten points in your example? What if I want to create a grid of a specified resolution in the plane, and then evaluate the integral at each of these grid points?

Comment: Let me comment that the approach depends strongly on the concrete form of the expression to be integrated. The one above, for example, admits passing to a single parameter: `(x Sin[t]+y Cos[t])^5/2==x^5/2*(Sin[t]+z*Cos[t])^5/2`where `z=y/x`. If this (or at least, something like this) is the case, the problem becomes especially simple.